# Can I move the contents of one vector to the end of another?

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, move-semantics

I want to do something like the following (`a` and `b` are both `vector<my_moveable_type>`):

```
a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

But I want the operation to move `b`'s elements into `a` instead of copying them. I have found `std::vector::emplace` but that is just for a single element, not a range.

Can this be done?

Comment: instead of moving the elements, I think you can move the whole lot when using `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`, though I don't quite know how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator), so that accesses to the iterator returns rvalue references instead of lvalue references:

```
a.insert(a.end(), std::make_move_iterator(b.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(b.end()));
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) algorithm that appears to do what you want. In the following code the source `std::vector` is left with empty strings (the vector size doesn't change).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> one{"cat", "dog", "newt"};
    std::vector<std::string> two;

    std::move(begin(one), end(one), back_inserter(two));

    std::cout << "one:\n";
    for (auto& str : one) {
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "two:\n";
    for (auto& str : two) {
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Working code at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6zaB8N)

Comment: Note that `std::back_inserter` can be quite slow if you're adding a lot of items, since it adds them one at a time. So it can cause multiple reallocations when that's not needed. Prefer `insert` where possible.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Or... just call `one.reserve(one.size() + two.size());` beforehand.